# What issue prevents Tails 2.3 starting from USB disk on iMac after Tails Installer installs to USB disk?

Tags: tails

With version 1, Tails was working fine. With the release of version 2, Tails stopped working fine. Previously, with Tails v1, after Tails Installer installed to the same USB disk I'm using today on the same iMac computer I'm using today, Tails successfully started from USB disk. However, Tails v2 fails to do the same.

Previously, after the Tails Installer installed v1.4 and each of the subsequent updates v1.5, v1.6, v1.7 and v1.8 to the same USB disk I'm using today on the same iMac computer I'm using today, Tails successfully started from the USB disk without any problems. The problem began with the release of Tails v2.

Tails v2 will start from USB disk only after manual installation of Tails to the USB disk. If the Tails Installer installs to the USB disk, Tails fails to start successfully from the USB disk.

My goal is for Tails v2.3 to start successfully from the USB disk after the Tails Installer installs to the USB disk because of course a user cannot open and configure a Tails ▸ Applications ▸ [Persistence volume](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/use/index.en.html) unless Tails starts from a USB disk on which Tails Installer has done the Tails installation.